# Let Google know about migration of my Blogger page

Tags: blogger

I have a Blogger page and I plan to make its contents (or simply migrate it) available at another website as some other page. I have heard about 301 re-directs that help Google identify site changes, but on Blogger there's no such feature.

What should I do to have all the credits linked with the old Blogger page be simply reflected to my new page?

Comment: Questions about search engine indexing / SEO are better server at [webmasters.se]. [\[seo\]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine-indexing) has more than 10,000 questions, [\[search-engine-indexing\]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine-indexing) has more than 800 questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is (deliberately) no feature for 301 re-directs in Blogger.

I assume that you plan to delete the contents from Blogger when you have moved them to the other site (to avoid duplicate content problems.)

You could set up a custom 404 error page which tells human visitors which website to find the contents  (under Settings > Search Preferences > Custom Page not found (edit link) ).   Google will also follow this link to re-index the content at the new location.

And if you have set up the blog in Webmaster Tools, I believe there is a feature there where you can tell Google about your site moving.    (Sorry, don't know the details of it.)   But I don't think you can do that for each individual post.

Comment: It is interesting to note that Google doesn't show my new site in the searches no matter how exact I search. Do you think it's because of the duplicate content matter as I have not deleted my old page data (just set up a redirect using JS).

Comment: How long was there between loading the content to the new site, and doing the test-searches?    Google doesn't index new sites immediately.

Comment: 10 days, I suppose. However I believe something is wrong as even searching the site URL returns nothing `clipjump.sourceforge.net`.

Comment: if you get no results when you search for   site:clipjump.sourceforge.net, then it means that Google has not indexed the site, and thus it cannot be included in search results.   However when I execute that search, I go get some results.   So It may be that Google just does not deem your content applies for the searches that you did.

Comment: Interesting site:<site> shows me only new pages of the site which are less active. It doesn't show the main index page of the site which is most active and unluckily is also duplicate. I tried `rel-canonical` and then reindexed it from Google Webmasters .